# color set on andengine library

Tags: java, android, colors, andengine

I'm making a little game using the ANDengine library,so I'm trying to set a text color to draw with changeableText(), but it seems that it doesn't accept html format or RGB, and it uses a system based on 4 colors, where every color must be under one!! does any one now wich system does ANDengine uses?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply divide your R, G and B numbers into 255 and set that to the color constructor. for example with the `RGB = (255, 0, 25)` you should use this color: `new Color(1f, 0, 0.1f)` the fourth number (or maybe the first one) must be transparency.

Comment: it works and give the same red, thanks, but where I can find the information of how this conversion works to convert other colors!!

Comment: thanks for the info I've already found the conversion system and already everything is working fine.